# Override a pathauto alias display with a view

Tags: views, nodes, path-aliases

I have a magazine style site with a lot of content types and automated path aliases. For a section of my site I already have views that display the content in a manor in which I want it displayed - I show the view by using a title argument. I am redoing that section of the website so that the titles are semantically cleaner but I still want to use the view to display the content. However when I convert the nodes to the new path aliases the default template file from the theme loads instead of my view.

Is there anyway to using an automated path to display a view?

For example my current content type creates the url sitename/[title] but the actual url that loads in the browser when you visit that node is sitetitle/magazinetitle/[title] the view finds the title and loads correctly (the links are generated using javascript). I want to move the path's into Drupal native to make it easier to update for someone using content type and views with limited knowledge of scripting. So the new url will be sitetitle/magazinetitle/[title] within the url alias section but when you visit that url it loads the node template from the theme instead of triggering the view to load.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what you are asking. You want, for one or more of your content types, to show a View instead of the usual node?

Comment: Yes, in essence. I don't want to recode all of my views as templates in the theme files so that my content editors can still manipulate the views without knowing php.

Comment: Look at this question - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88920/view-for-full-content - if that is similar, see if any of the suggestions work for you. Check out all the answers, they have different ideas of how to go forward.